# Aws lambda use custom linuix command from preinstalled binaries

Tags: ffmpeg, aws-lambda, serverless

I want to `ffmpeg` with my lambda, But I don't know my runtime(unix or?) env, so I cannot copy the binary directly.

I can install the library on every invocation of my lambda, which seems like a wasted effort and money. Please suggest any alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lambda offers the ability to prepackaged shared code via layers. These layers can be shared publicly, and fortunately an ffmpeg layer has already been built:

https://serverlessrepo.aws.amazon.com/applications/arn:aws:serverlessrepo:us-east-1:145266761615:applications~ffmpeg-lambda-layer

Use this as a layer in your lambda function, and you'll be able to use ffmpeg without worrying about the details.

Answer (score 1):

AWS Lambda runs on Amazon Linux or Amazon Linux 2, depending on the function runtime. You can find the full list [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html).

You can run an EC2 instance running either of the two in order to compile and test your executable.

The [Serverless Video Preview and Analysis Service](https://github.com/laardee/video-preview-and-analysis-service) project uses ffmpeg in a lambda function to perform video processing. You can find there a way to package an ffmpeg executable with a lambda function.